# Using thread for periodically check the value of a variable in a class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, executorservice

Hy everyone,

i'm writing a class that is using a thread but i've got this problem. This is the scenario: a GUI Java application interact with  a class A that is a sort of a manager, this class create and serve a request using a thread create with ExcutorService. The request comes from the gui user input. The manager class A create a thread with ExecutorService, update the value of a request and set it to true or false according to some specific condition

```
class Manager {

private Request request;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private void serve(){

Launch a thread and serve request
executor.submit(someThread)

}
```

Request is an object the contains a boolean variable; this class should be this:

```
class Request {

private boolean isFinish = false
....

}
```

Manager Class is using from a Java GUI application. I would like that my Gui ask to manager Class to launch a second Thread to check and get periodically the value from the request. The value should be return by the class manager and should be available to application gui. This operation should be asyncronus in order to evoid freezing of gui application. If the value isFinish is false, the gui show in a box the message "Thread is not already finished"; if the value isFinish is false the gui in a box the message "Thread is finished"

Comment: Please format your code blocks with ``` at the start and end, or using the editor {} button to format your code for you.

Comment: the solution is not wrong ..... probabily you will not understand my problems; polling is required by the gui that display string "thread has not been finish" if the variable is set to false;

Comment: Tip: when you want to alert someone with a message, add @username (for example @c0der) to it.  AlBlue did not offer a solution but asked you to format the posted code. What is the required process ? Gui click > invokes manager > manager issues request ? request processed > result displayed on gui ? [mre] would be best